# python - tornado not redirecting to new dummy page

Tags: python, redirect, tornado

I am using tornado and here is the code for my main handler -

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        self.render("homepage.html", messages=ChatSocketHandler.browser_cache)

#
# HTTP *POST* HANDLER
#
    def post(self):
        print "Post received"
        post_body = self.get_argument("body")
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        self.redirect("test.html")
```

The test.html file is simple -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>

     <h1>My First Heading</h1>

     <p>My first paragraph.</p>

     </body>
   </html>
```

I put it both, in the same folder as the python server file and also in the templates directory. Yet, when the post handler is called, the page does not redirect to this file instead giving me a 404.

```
[W 151101 22:35:44 web:1825] 404 GET /test.html (::1) 1.00ms
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a handler for your `test.html` route ?

Comment: You are redirecting in your post handler, and performing a GET request, that ain't gonna work. Change the redirect to the GET handler or perform a POST request. That should work.

Comment: @Roy - please pardon my ignorance. Is it possible at all to redirect from the POST handler?

Comment: @Christian - Sorry, but how do I add such a handler. I thought we could only use generic get and post handlers

Comment: @RohitPandey - Sure, that is no problem. After submitting a form using the POST method, you want to redirect to a GET page so the user won't submit the form again when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting an html file in the same directory as your python file doesn't do anything in Tornado: you must tell the python server to serve this file. In general, for every top-level file in your templates directory you should create a handler that calls `self.render()` for that template, and create a route for that file in your application definition.

If you don't want to use any template features in this file, you could put it in your `static_path` instead of `template_path`, and then it would be served automatically as `/static/index.html`. But it sounds like you probably want this file to evolve towards being a more full-featured handler.