# Rendering a new page in the post handler works in some cases and not others

Tags: python, post, render, tornado

I've already asked a question about this before here - [python - tornado not redirecting to new dummy page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472847/python-tornado-not-redirecting-to-new-dummy-page)
but the issue remains unresolved for me. Now, it has become more confusing than ever since it seems to work in some situations but not in others.

A few weeks ago, I decided to start form scratch and started reading the book - http://file.allitebooks.com/20150514/Introduction%20to%20Tornado.pdf

In chapter 2 (page 13), there is poemmaker.py which has a redirect in the POST handler and it works beautifully.

```
class PoemPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        noun1 = self.get_argument('noun1')
        noun2 = self.get_argument('noun2')
        verb = self.get_argument('verb')
        noun3 = self.get_argument('noun3')
        self.render('poem.html', roads=noun1, wood=noun2, made=verb, difference=noun3)
```

Then in chapter 5 (page 84), you have shopping_cart.py as an example of long polling. This code has a very similar looking post handler -

```
class CartHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        action = self.get_argument('action')
        session = self.get_argument('session')

        if not session:
            self.set_status(400)
            return
        if action == 'add':
            self.application.shoppingCart.moveItemToCart(session)
        elif action == 'remove':
            self.application.shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(session)
        else:
            self.set_status(400)
        #self.render('test.html')
```

Now, the self.render does not work (and I tried this same html file with poemmaker.py and it worked here, it just stays stuck on the same page and the browser becomes unresponsive). It seems to me like the same handler is behaving very differently in these two situations. What is the reason the render works in one case but not the other?

EDIT:
I found that there is a difference in the main methods for the two cases -

For poemhandler (where render works), it is defined as -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[(r'/', IndexHandler), (r'/poem', PoemPageHandler)],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
        )
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

While for shopping_cart it is defined as -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = Application()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The difference seems to be in the way the app object is defined which tells tornado where to find the templates. However, when I try to define the location of the templates directory in the second case, the whole page doesn't show up.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean with "the self.render does not work"? How are you testing those pages? Are you using some tool like Chrome Poster? What does tornado console logs say when you post some data?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I meet the same problem too. The solution is easy as follow:

In the file of shopping_cart.py,

```
settings = {
    'template_path': 'templates',
    'static_path': 'static'
}
```

should be revised to

```
import os.path
    ...
settings={
    'template_path':os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'),
    'static_path':os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static')
}
```